# Calendar in MS Teams not synced with Outlook

Tags: outlook, calendar, microsoft-teams

The office 365 email account is testuser@xyz.com, and the office 365 account is testuser@xyz.onmicrosoft.com. I signed in MS Teams via the account testuser@xyz.onmicrosoft.com. But its calendar (opened by the calendar button on the left sidebar) is completely empty and does not sync with the Outlook Calendar. I am able to schedule a meeting in Teams calendar. But it does not appear in my Outlook Calendar.
I went to https://teams.microsoft.com, and the Calendar button is not on the left sidebar. Actually, the Calendar button on the Teams Desktop just showed up or disappear, after a restart of the desktop app, for no reason.
Also, the workstation is not in the Azure Active Directory of xyz.com. The windows user testuser is a windows local account

Answer (score 1):

I realized that xyz.com and xyz.onmicrosoft.com are two different platforms. They are hosted by different hosting companies and there is no sync between the two platforms.